# Getting auto-generated value on insert with JPA 2

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa-2.0

I am using JPA 2 to model some entities in my application. In some of the models, there are particular columns whose value is populated on insert. An example of such column would be:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "timestamp", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Calendar timestamp;
```

Now I would like that on save, the generated value of the column would be populated automatically so that it's available from the application code. With Hibernate, I can use the [`@Generated`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Generated.html) annotation, however I would like to keep ORM specific code out of my application and use native JPA only.

Is this possible with just native JPA?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: So do you want to automatically populate from the database or application?

Comment: Database ideally. I would not have this problem if I populate the field from the application as all I would need to do is set `insertable="true"`

Comment: IMO: it is nearly impossible to stay with pure JPA in a serious enterprise application. It shouldn't be a problem anyway to use ORM specific features; switching persistence provider is just as bad an idea as it is to switch DBMS. Besides, you're always free to just deploy the persistence provider with your application, you can't really run into compatibility issues.

Comment: @is-serp Couldn't you create a db trigger to do this work?  I'm assuming your trying to input the current date/time.  A trigger and a call to flush should give you the new date in the object

Comment: @KevinBowersox The column already has a default value, so generating that value is not an issue. The issue is getting a generated value back in the application automatically on insert.

Comment: @Gimby true. My only concern would be more when upgrading the JPA provider than switching to another one. But then again I could run in the same issue when upgrading to a newer version of JPA.

Comment: @is-serp shouldn't a call to flush realign the db and object?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yes it should but I was afraid that it would be rather expensive since it synchronizes the whole of the persistence context. On the other hand, `refresh()` on the entity might do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remain with this logic in the JPA I suppose the life [cycle listeners](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html) could be of help.